# vimrc key remap seems to not work, but works in :Ex mode

Tags: vim

In my vimrc, I have the following:

```
imap <S-Tab> <Esc><<i
```

This will unindent by 1 tabs-length Shift+Tab in insert mode. Shift-Tab acts as if it is just a Tab when I have this in my vimrc though. However, if I run the following in :Ex mode:

```
:imap <S-Tab> <Esc><<i
```

The remapping works properly. Does anyone know what might be causing the problem? There is no other remapping of  in the vimrc. I ran

```
strace -o vim_strace vim
```

to verify that the correct vimrc is being sourced and no other strange vimrc's are being sourced.

Interestingly, I have the same exact vimrc on my local machine, and it works properly. That is, this problem is only occurring on a remote machine I am ssh'd into.

Does anyone have any ideas that might help solve this annoying problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the mapping because you can use a built in command `<c-d>` in insert mode. Think of it as decrease indent. See `:h i_ctrl_d` for more information.

If you wish to use `<s-tab>` then map `<s-tab>` to `<c-d>` by insert the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
inoremap <s-tab> <c-d>
```

It should be noted that not all terminals can distinguish between `<tab>` and `<s-tab>`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am aware of <c-d>, but wanted to basically remap that to <S-Tab>. <S-Tab> doing the reverse of what <Tab> does feels so much more natural due to this behavior in so many other applications. Regardless of what I should and shouldn't be using, shouldn't I be able to map this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the mapping is overridden.

```
:verbose imap <S-Tab>
```

will tell you.

It may also be that `<S-Tab>` isn't properly handled in the terminal, and Vim just receives a plain `<Tab>`. You can check by entering `<C-V><S-Tab>` in insert mode, and check what gets inserted.